AERODYNAMIC FORCES ON DOWNSTREAM TURBINE DUE TO WAKE
I want to perform fatigue analysis on downstream turbine blades, but I want to do this analysis with the aerodynamic forces caused by wake effects. Is it possible to find such data for downstream turbines?
